# Can't access array element in render mode even if it exists

Tags: android, react-native, redux-saga

I have React native project with redux state manager, using redux-saga and immer for dealing with immutables. There is a simple screen, where i fetch news, using onFocusEffect(). I get data correctly (debug with flipper and redux debugger plugin), but when i try to access news.news.headerImages[0] my app crashes with ERROR TypeError: Cannot convert undefined value to object.
So, here is the code:

Action creator:

```
const startLoadNews = (id) => {
  return { type: Types.START_LOAD_NEWS, id };
};
```

Saga:

```
    function* fetchNews(action) {
      try {
        const news =  yield call(FakeApi.getNewsLocal, action.id);
        yield put(newsActions.loadNewsSuccess(news));
      } catch (error) {
        yield put(newsActions.loadNewsError('Cant load news'));
      }
    }

    function* watchNews() {
      yield takeLatest(types.START_LOAD_NEWS, fetchNews);
    }

    export function* newsSaga() {
      yield all([watchNews()]);
    }
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  news: {},
  loading: false,
  error: '',
};

export const newsReducer = (state = initialState, action) =>
  produce(state, draft => {
    switch (action.type) {
      case types.START_LOAD_NEWS:
        draft.loading = true;
        draft.error = '';
        draft.news = {};
      break;
      case types.LOAD_NEWS_SUCCESS:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.error = '';
        draft.news = {...action.news};
      break;
      case types.LOAD_NEWS_ERROR:
        draft.loading = false;
        draft.error = action.error;
        draft.news = {};
      break;
    }
  });
```

And my NewsScreen component, connected to store:

```
export const NewsScreen = (params) => {

  const { route, news, loadNews } = params;
  const { newsId } = route.params;

  useFocusEffect(
    useCallback(() => { loadNews(newsId); }, [])
  );

  const testImg = 'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/confident-business-team-with-leader_1098-3228.jpg';

  return (
    news.loading ? (
      <Spinner/>
    ) : (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <ScrollView>

          {true && (
            <TouchableOpacity>
            <ImageBackground style={styles.image} source={{uri: news.news.headerImages[0]}}>
            <View style={styles.notifyer}>
              <Notifyer>1-3</Notifyer>
              </View>
            </ImageBackground>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          )}

          <View style={styles.content}>
            <View style={styles.header}>
              <Text style={styles.dimmed}>{jsDateTodmY(news.news.date)} | <Text>{news.news.category} </Text></Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.textArea}>
              <Text style={styles.newsText}>{news.news.fullText}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.footer}>
              <Text style={styles.sourceTitle}>Source</Text>
              <Text style={styles.source}>{news.news.source}</Text>
            </View>
          </View>
        </ScrollView>
      </View>
    )
  );
};
```

So, if i replace **news.news.headerImages[0]** with **testImg** it loads good, event if i access to news object below in code. Where i do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out:

After first render there is no news.news.headerImages array of my state, so when i try to acccess to undefined.[index] it crashes. Fixed it by adding an array to my initial state:

```
const initialState = {
  news: { headerImages:[] },
  loading: false,
  error: '',
};
```